# Yet another slow plot involving numerical integration

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration, performance-tuning

Well, after reading a lot about how plotting expressions involving `NIntegrate` can take a lot of time, and how to overcome this issue with `DSolve`, I still have problems when plotting this function:

```
myfunction[delta_] = 
 5*(2 + 3*NIntegrate[(E^(-(1/2) (-((3 Sqrt[5/2] delta)/(-1 + delta)) +
                t)^2) (1 + 
           E^(-((3 Sqrt[10] delta t)/(-1 + delta)))) GammaRegularized[
          9/2, 0, (0.222222 (4.74342 + (-1. + 1. delta) t)^2)/(-1. + 
              delta)^2])/Sqrt[2 \[Pi]], {t, 
       0, (3*Sqrt[10])/(2*(1 - delta))}, AccuracyGoal -> Infinity, 
          Method -> {"LocalAdaptive", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}, 
      MaxRecursion -> 100] - 
      3*NIntegrate[(E^(-(1/2) (-((3 Sqrt[5/2] delta)/(-1 + delta)) + 
               t)^2) (1 + 
           E^(-((3 Sqrt[10] delta t)/(-1 + delta)))) GammaRegularized[
          9/2, 0, 1/18 ((3 Sqrt[5/2])/(-1 + delta) + t)^2])/
       Sqrt[2 \[Pi]], 
          {t, 0, (3*Sqrt[10])/(2*(1 - delta))}, 
      AccuracyGoal -> Infinity, 
          Method -> {"LocalAdaptive", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}, 
      MaxRecursion -> 100])

Plot[myfunction[delta], {delta, 0, 1}]
```

It won't finish after serval minutes.

I used `AccuracyGoal -> Infinity` and so because, when calculating and plotting the result of the integration separately, I get better results.

So, is there any way to speed up this plot (and the calculation itself, as a matter of fact)? What am I missing?

Comment: You put high `AccuracyGoal`, but your numerical constants are just in machine precision.

Comment: Should I remove the accuracy goal?

Comment: I would say so, but it does not matter much. In any case, I can do plot in 6 seconds in the range (0,0.95) and 7 seconds in (0,1). There is a problem at 1. I have MA11

Comment: @yarchik I thought that it was better not to use `:=` when it comes to plotting 'resource-demanding' functions.

Comment: @yarchik Seconds?? It takes me an eternity, not seconds, with Mathematica 11.3.  :/

Comment: @yarchik Sorry, did you also remove any of the options in `NIntegrate`?

Comment: @yarchik Sorry, but not for me. I did `Quit`, I even exited Mathematica. Then I started a fresh new session, I changed `=` by `:=` and removed `AccuracyGoal`, as you said, but only when limiting `delta` between 0 and 0.8 I get the plot in few seconds. If I want to go up to 0.85, it doesn't seem to end execution. I am asking this here because I already tried all the typical tricks.  :/

Comment: `NIntegrate` uses `AccuracyGoal -> Infinity` by default. It means that `PrecisionGoal` determines convergence.

Comment: Can you provide a link or reference for how `DSolve` can be used to speed up plotting involving expressions with `NIntegrate`? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Update: Typo in the original code made it work more easily.*

---

1. Compute one integral, not two.
2. Don't use `"LocalAdaptive"` -- it's usually slower except when it isn't (and sometimes it isn't).
3. Use `MaxRecursion -> 0` in `Plot` to experiment with possible solutions. (It showed rather quickly there was a discontinuity around `0.8`. Suddenly, the plot jumped to zero. Numerics problem? Underflow? Increase working precision?)
4. `EvaluationMonitor` confirmed that when `MaxRecursion` is raised a little, `Plot` gets bogged down around `0.8`.
5. I guessed where the floating-point numbers came from and substituted exact formulas, so that I could raise `WorkingPrecision`.
6. (*Update.*) The actual problem exceeds the limits of bignums as `delta` approaches `1` (around `delta == 1 = 1*^-3`).  It appears this causes the problems with the integration. If we reflect the interval and replace `t` by `Exp[t]`, the effective support of the integrand becomes a larger proportion of the interval of integration -- and whether or not those are the reasons, the integration is done more easily by `NIntegrate` until around `delta == 1 = 1*^-7`.  Not much gain I guess, unless you're interested in `delta -> 0`.  The plot below seems to work, but that's probably because it does not get so close to the end point `delta == 1`.

Code:

```
integrand[t_, delta_] := ((E^(-(1/2) (-((3 Sqrt[5/2] delta)/(-1 + delta)) + 
             t)^2) (1 + 
         E^(-((3 Sqrt[10] delta t)/(-1 + delta)))) GammaRegularized[9/
        2, 0, (2 (3 Sqrt[5/2] + (-1 + 1 delta) t)^2)/(
        9 (-1 + delta)^2)])/Sqrt[2 π]) -
   ((E^(-(1/2) (-((3 Sqrt[5/2] delta)/(-1 + delta)) + t)^2) (1 + 
         E^(-((3 Sqrt[10] delta t)/(-1 + delta)))) GammaRegularized[
        9/2, 0, 1/18 ((3 Sqrt[5/2])/(-1 + delta) + t)^2])/
     Sqrt[2 π]);

myfunction[delta_] := 
  5*(2 + 3 (NIntegrate[
       Exp[t] integrand[(3*Sqrt[10])/(2*(1 - delta)) - Exp[t], delta],
       {t, -Infinity, (3*Sqrt[10])/(2*(1 - delta)) // Log},
       WorkingPrecision -> 32, PrecisionGoal -> 6]));

Plot[myfunction[delta], {delta, 0, 1}(*, MaxRecursion->0*), 
  WorkingPrecision -> 32, 
  PlotRange -> {myfunction[0] - 0.5, All}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

[image]

(`Plot` gives a precision warning because, even though WP -> 32 is specified, it tests the function by plugging in a machine-precision float.)

Comment: You have an extra factor of 3 on the second term in your integral.

Comment: @bRost03 Good catch! Thanks.